# Mulitple versions of a kafka clients bundle is not working in OSGi KARAF

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-camel, osgi, maven-plugin

I am using karaf container to deploy my bundles which consists of the following structure.

> - external bundle which expects kafka clients 0.9.0.0(strict)
> - bundle A(my own bundle) which uses camel kafka(2.25.2) expects 0.11.0 because of newly added package(org.apache.kafka.common.header) in 0.11.0 which is used in camel-kafka- 2.25.2.

```
mybundle 
    - camel-kafka
        - kafka-clients - 0.11.0.0
other-client-bundles(external bundles)
    - kafka-clients-0.9.0.0
```

When i am trying to publish my file to outside world which is not happening because of multiple versions of kafka are in karaf. Producer is getting created with first reference of kafka-client(here 0.9.0.0).
I tried to embed dependency the karaf-clients 0.11.0.0 in to my bundle A using maven bundle plugin. Still files are not getting published. when i packed with Embed-Dependency it should take the local bundles in the classpath(same classloader). When i try with servicemix bundles for kafka bundles same issue persists.
Here one bundle is my own bundle which i am trying to embed .and the other bundle is from other source which expects strict version. Also camel-kafka expects version 0.11.0 which i can't change. Any help will be appreciated to solve this.

```
<plugin>
                 <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
              <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>4.2.1</version>
                 <extensions>true</extensions>
                 <configuration>
                     <instructions>
                             com.java.test.pack*,
                             com.java.test.pack.internal.*,
                             com.java.test.pack.utils.*,
                           com.java.test.pack.reports.*                        
                           com.java.test.pack.reporting.*,
                           org.apache.kafka.common.header*
                  </Export-Package>
                   <Import-Package>!com.ibm.security*,!sun.security*,*</Import-Package>
                       <Embed-Dependency>kafka-clients</Embed-Dependency>
                     </instructions>
                 </configuration>
             </plugin>
```

Comment: Why not add exclusion blocks to the POM dependencies?

Comment: I am not packaging anyways in my package. Also i tried with inline for both camel-kafka and kafka-clients with specific versions. still not sending.

Comment: <Import-Package>!com.ibm.security*,!sun.security*,org.apache.kafka*,*</Import-Package>
+                   <Embed-Dependency>kafka-clients;scope=compile|runtime;inline=false;version=0.11.0.0,camel-kafka;scope=compile|runtime;inline=false;version=2.25.2</Embed-Dependency> Tried this too. still not working.. kafka component is not getting loaded..Lookup Component with name kafka in registry. Found: null

Comment: If you are not packaging, then what is the build output? A "karaf container" will still need to use .class/jar files... I've never used the `maven-bundle-plugin`, so I dont know how that works, but you should be able to have a separate `<dependency>` tags with `kafka-clients` and that'll include it in the classpath for the app

Comment: What meant was i am not packaging the kafka-clients explicitly and listing in bundles. Instead its embedded inside my bundle. So by default it should take the karaf component from mybundle.